# Code making a lot of unnecessary Firestore Read Operations

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, get, use-effect

Hi I am currently making a blog, which uses Firestore to store the blog posts then read and displayed in my home page. It also includes authentication through Firebase. For some reason I keep reaching the free daily quota of 50k reads, even though there are never more than a few documents stored and rarely any refreshing. The app is only available to me on my local hardware.

The amount of reads should be in the teens, but ends up being thousands for each refresh of the page.

The only times I actually connect to the database is when I use the UseEffect on the homepage so it must be that but im not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I had deletePost in the dependency it still was having the same effect.

Here is the Home page which is where UseEffect is used and reads from firestore to display the data.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {getDocs, collection} from "firebase/firestore";
import {db} from "../../services/firebase";
import "./Home.css";
import MultiActionAreaCard from '../../components/postCard/postCard';
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';


function Home({isAuth}) {
    const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);
    const postsCollectionRef = collection(db, "Posts");

    useEffect(() => {
        const getPosts = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(postsCollectionRef);
            setPostList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
        }
        getPosts();
    }, [ postsCollectionRef]);

    
    return (
        <div className='homePage'>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
            {postList.map((post) => {
                return (
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                        <MultiActionAreaCard title={post.title} author={post.author.name} authorID={post.author.id} post={post.postText} isAuth={isAuth} id={post.id}/>
                    </Grid>
            )})}
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Home;
```

Here is the deletePost function which is within the MultiActionAreaCard, used to connect to firestore and delete the post just in case. Only called when the delete button is clicked.

```
   const deletePost = async (id) => {
    const postDoc = doc(db, "Posts", id )
    await deleteDoc(postDoc);
```

if there's anything else you'd like me to include to help you all help me, please let me know! it won't let me post images since I don't have 10 reputations but most days it states I have 51k reads and only 2-3 writes and deletes. So, the other metrics are working as they should except read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing what or how this `Home` component is rendered or anything else your app may be doing with your firestore, it seems likely that since `postsCollectionRef` is a new reference any time this  `Home` component renders that this is triggering the `useEffect` hook callback also on each render.

If nothing else references `postsCollectionRef` then move it either *outside* the component ***or*** into the `useEffect`'s callback scope so it can be removed as an external dependency. This allows you to use an empty dependency so the `useEffect` hook callback is called only once when the `Home` component mounts.

```
const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const postsCollectionRef = collection(db, "Posts");

  const getPosts = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(postsCollectionRef);
    setPostList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
  }

  getPosts();
}, []);
```

If on the other hand `postsCollectionRef` ***is*** referenced elsewhere, then again, either move it *outside* the component or memoize it's value so it's a stable reference from render to render.

```
const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);
const postsCollectionRef = useRef(collection(db, "Posts"));

useEffect(() => {
  const getPosts = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(postsCollectionRef.current);
    setPostList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
  }

  getPosts();
}, []);

// use postsCollectionRef.current elsewhere for accesses
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the help, I can't check to see if it actually works until tomorrow since I'm over the quota but I will definitely update you, but nonetheless thank you! it does make sense. Also postsCollectionRef is only referenced in Home.tsx and Home.tsx is rendered in App.js rendered with a Route element={<Home isAuth={isAuth}/>}

Comment: @CalvinCosta Hi, did you get a chance to try this solution?

Comment: I did actually!! It works as expected, thank you. However I then run into an issue where the page won’t instantly display a post is deleted until the home page is refreshed which makes sense. I’ll try and make the refresh seamless by adding a “are you sure” prompt which triggers a refresh when deleting cause I currently don’t know of another solution

Comment: @CalvinCosta Great, and ah, ok. Glad it works for the operations part. How are you deleting posts? It may be worth a new post. If anything you'll get more eyes on the issue more quickly with a new post. Feel free to ping (@ me) here with a link to it and I can take a look as well. It sounds like a stale state issue from what you describe.